# jaxb wsdl-to-java, make the class not abstract

Tags: xml, binding, jaxb, wsdl, abstract

The wsdl file content piece is as below:

```
 <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="timeZone">
     <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="rawOffset" type="xs:int"/>
     </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

When I use jaxb to generate the java class, it's a abstract class.
So I need a bindings xml file to make it not abstract.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../JConfigManager.wsdl#types1"
    node="//xs:schema//xs:complexType[@name='timeZone']">
    <!--Something to make the class not abstract-->
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Please help on the bindings xml file, I could not make change on wsdl file.